# Airflow how transferring between two remote servers

Tags: ssh, airflow

Good day !!! SFTPOperator for transferring to (from) a remote server, Is there an operator for transferring between two remote servers ?? Or just SSHOperator in hand with scp command ????

Answer (score 0):

Use two [SFTPOperators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/index.html). First download the file then upload it like `download_from_remote_1 >> upload_to_remote_2`.

It's important to make sure that the file is accessible between two tasks, so you either have to make sure those two run on the same machine or use some intermittent storage like GCS bucket (then you have [ready made operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/index.html) for that. Second option is recommended.